# How to feed multiple options to a command from a file?

Tags: command-line, bash

I want to feed the list of options sitting in a local file to a command

- **Example1:**
  path of files to be deleted are in a file. How would you feed these paths to `sudo rm -rf` ?
  **
- **Example2**
  list of name of packages are in a file. How would you feed these to `sudo apt-get install`?

Examples are for better understanding of my question... answers *need not* be specific to the examples... you can cite even more complex situation and solution to it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
xargs -a file_name command --initial-argument --another-initial-argument
```

Comment: How would you specify the delimiter... it could be `tab` , `comma`, or `new line`??

Comment: Spaces if no spaces in pathnames. New lines otherwise.

Comment: i did'nt get that !!!

Comment: Sorry, I've missread. Thougth 'how you choose delimiter'. You enter delimiter via -d option after filename. More details in man xargs